# sendmsg fails with error code 3 (ESRCH )

Tags: linux, network-programming, udp

OS: Linux 2.6.24 (x86)

My application runs on a server where several clients connects to it on UDP port 4500.
Intermittently, application fails to send UDP traffic to clients on UDP port 4500

This is because sendmsg system-call fails with error code 3 (ESRCH )
man page for sendmsg doesn't talk about error ESRCH

Problem doesn't resolve even after killing the application and relaunching it.
UDP traffic on other ports working fine

Rebooting the server is the only solution.

With kernel 2.6.11, I haven't seen issues like this.

Any idea on how to debug this issue ?

Comment: How did you figure out that error code 3 corresponds to ESRCH?

Comment: $ grep ESRCH include/asm-generic/errno-base.h 
#define ESRCH   3 /* No such process */

Comment: i sent an invite to alan@lxorguk.ukuu.org.uk

Comment: Can you post a sample of your server code with the socket setup and servicing bits that fail? Also are you running are firewall?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?  I'm getting the same error when trying to do a "sendto" to the broadcast address.

Comment: No answers, how sad! Surely there is ESRCH in kernel source somewhere!

Answer (score 2):

To debug this issue, given the information available I think the best starting place is to see if there is a way that `sendmsg` can return `ESRCH`. First we need to get the source for the particular kernel version you have seen the issue on, I found it [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/)

After some digging we can see that the following chain may execute:

```
net/ipv4/udp.c:646:     
    err = ip_route_output_flow(&rt, &fl, sk, 1);

net/ipv4/route.c:2421:
    err = __xfrm_lookup((struct dst_entry **)rp, flp, sk, flags);

net/xfrm/xfrm_policy.c:1380:
    pols[1] = xfrm_policy_lookup_bytype(XFRM_POLICY_TYPE_MAIN,
                            fl, family,
                            XFRM_POLICY_OUT);

net/xfrm/xfrm_policy.c:890:
    err = xfrm_policy_match(pol, fl, type, family, dir);
```

Finally, we end up at `net/xfrm/xfrm_policy.c:854:xrfm_policy_match`

```
/*
 * Find policy to apply to this flow.
 *
 * Returns 0 if policy found, else an -errno.
 */
static int xfrm_policy_match(struct xfrm_policy *pol, struct flowi *fl,
             u8 type, u16 family, int dir)
{
    struct xfrm_selector *sel = &pol->selector;
    int match, ret = -ESRCH;

    if (pol->family != family ||
        pol->type != type)
        return ret;

    match = xfrm_selector_match(sel, fl, family);
    if (match)
        ret = security_xfrm_policy_lookup(pol, fl->secid, dir);

    return ret;
}
```

So, it looks like the error is coming from `xfrm_policy_match` if you inspect code in `xfrm_lookup_bytype` you will find a loop that continues until an iterator is exhausted or the return value of `xrfm_policy_match` is not `ESRCH`.

This tells us that your sendmsg calls are failing because there is no xfrm policy for your port. As you state that it works, then the error occurs and persists this suggests that the xfrm policies on your system are being tweaked or corrupted.

From looking at the xfrm man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-xfrm.8.html) we can see that there are some tools for investigating the policies. From reading the man page my next step would be running `ip xfrm state list` when the issue has not occurred and after it has occurred and comparing the output. Unfortunately I don't have a running system with a 2.6.24 kernel to dig any deeper.

Note that I don't have any tricks to arrive at this conclusion, it was determined through inspection of the code, grepping and finding. This can take a lot of time and effort especially when you are not familiar with a code base. To fix the issue as opposed to debug it I would of tried different kernel versions before digging this deep.

---

### TL;DR

It looks like the `ESRCH` error comes from a network subsystem called `xfrm`, there are a set of tools for investigating `xfrm` which can be found on its man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-xfrm.8.html)

It seems most likely that the error is due to a missing policy for the address/port you are trying to send to. This may be due to a configuration change while the system is running or a bug causing corruption of the xfrm policies.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error on OSX when a host on my LAN was unreachable (ethernet unplugged).  So, it appears it may be triggered by a variety of conditions.  Possibly the (airport) router generated an ICMP.